# amazon ec2 elastic ip. do I need one for each website I host?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-elastic-ip

I have a couple of sites that I want to move to Amazon EC2. All the sites uses ssl so it needs to have a dedicated ip address to each one.
My question is: Even if I host all the sites in the same instance, do I need to get one elastic ip for each site?

Comment: While a dedicated IP for each SSL identity is preferred for compatibility - you cannot associated multiple elastic IP addressed with a single EC2 instance, so would need multiple instances as well for your scenario. (With VPC you can add 2 elastic network interfaces, and associate an elastic IP with each, but that still only allows a small number of IP addresses to be associated with a instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are [some solutions](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) that allow multiple SSL identity certificates on a single IP address, in general if you require good browser compatibility, then you will require an IP per Certificate. There are some details on why this is the case in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/367006/ssl-and-serveralias-on-one-apache-server-with-multiple-domains/367019#367019)

The problem for standard Name-based Virtual Hosts is basically that the first thing that the https server does during the TLS/SSL handshake is send the SSL certificate with a "common name" identifying itself as www.mysecuresite.com - However Name virtualhosts relies on a "Hosts:" header to decide which site which is sent later during the HTTP phase.

Hence (using traditional... SSL v1, old browsers etc, Windows XP) there can only be 1 SSL identity per IP address, because the first thing the servername is already known as www.amazon.com, which it cannot change afterwards...

**Notes**  -generally these are for fairly niche situations, such as intranet or *.mydomain.com wildcard certs.

Server Name Indication, is a solution for hosting multiple SSL certs on a single IP, but it has poor support:

- not XP or old safari, or old android - works with only 1 IP - http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI"
- Wildcard certs, not suitable in this particular situation because the servers names are domain level, eg badger.com and monkey.com, rather than badger.server.com and monkey.server.com

Comment: SAN certificates are more widely supported than SNI and are a good solution if you only have a few domains.  Most of them support up to 25.

Answer (score 1):

You can't associate multiple Elastic IP addressees with a single normal EC2 instance.

You can have multiple ELB's in front of a single instance with each one getting its own IP address and proxying to a different port on the instance.

Comment: Plus, you can do SSL termination at the ELB level, which simplifies SSL certificate management. That way, you wouldn't even need to proxy to different ports on the actual instance - a single port will do, receiving regular HTTP traffic.

Comment: Not correct anymore. Its nowadays supported with multiple elastic ips to one ec2.